# Error with firebase cloud store and uniqueID: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: typescript, database, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to create a uniqueID with 6 digits for each newly registered user and save it into firebase cloud store. Worth to mention, that firebase initialization works without problems, so there is something else. I may assume that my error is pretty obvious, however it's my first time working with firebase, so I can't see it, I have tried to change the rules but it still doesn't work.

**handleRegistration:**

```
      function generateCustomUserID() {
    const randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 100;
    const randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 900) + 100;
    const customID = `${randomNumber1}_${randomNumber2}`;
    console.log("Generated Custom ID:", customID); // Debug: Print the generated custom ID
    return customID;
  }

  const handleRegistration = async (
    values: any,
    setSubmitting: any,
    customID: string
  ) => {
    try {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        values.email,
        values.password
      );

      const uid = userCredential.user.uid;

      const db = getFirestore();

      // Check if the user is authenticated before proceeding with Firestore writes
      if (auth.currentUser) {
        const userRef = doc(db, "users", uid, "uniqueID", customID);
        const uniqueIDRef = doc(db, "uniqueID", customID);

        await setDoc(userRef, {
          displayName: values.fullName,
          email: values.email,
        });

        await setDoc(uniqueIDRef, {
          customID: customID,
        });

        console.log("User registered successfully:", userCredential.user);
        navigation.navigate("ProfileMaker");
      } else {
        console.error("User not authenticated.");
        // Handle the case where the user is not authenticated
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error registering user:", error);
      setSignupError("Registration failed, Please try again");
    }

    setSubmitting(false);
  };
```

**My firebase rules:**

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
match /uniqueID/{document} {
  allow create: if request.auth != null && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/uniqueID/$(document));
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
}
  }
}
```